# I'm trying to create a letter grade calculator but keep receiving errors

Tags: c#, xamarin

This the code that I have;
The items that I have is:

```
string gradepct = null;
int testScore = 100;
if (testScore <= 60) { gradepct = "F";}
else if (testScore < 69) {gradepct = "D";}
else if (testScore < 79) {gradepct = "C";}
else if (testScore < 89) {gradepct = "B";
} else {gradepct = "A";}
Console.WriteLine ("You have recived the grade of gradepct!");
Console.WriteLine ("Please enter a correct grade")
```

Comment: Post more of your code. We can't tell what's happening with this small amount of information.

Comment: The `;` between `110` and `testScore` looks wrong

Comment: an if-then in C# is `if (condition) { result; }`.  You appear to be packing the entire statement into the `condition`

Comment: I understand how to use the console.writeline but im using Xamarin workbooks

Comment: @Mikael I think that the code is actually enough to point out several problems in it. There might be problems elsewhere too, but I was able to point out at least 3 of them in my answer.

Comment: in your revised code you should use "<=" for comparison, not "<"

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
if (testScore >= 0 &&int gradepct = 110;testScore <=100)
```

You can't put `int gradepct = 110;` in the middle of the condition for your `if` statement like this. Also, you should use brackets after the `if` statement. Rewrite it to this:

```
int gradepct = 110;
if (testScore >= 0 && testScore <=100)
{
....
}
```

That actually won't work either, though - you made `gradepct` of type `int`, but you're trying to assign a `string` to it, e.g.:

```
gradepct = "C";
```

Also, it's a little unclear why you're assigning `110` to it in the first place - it'll always be set in the course of your `if` statements, so you really don't need to set it to anything in particular.

You should do the following instead:

```
string gradepct = null;
if (testScore >= 0 && testScore <=100)
{
...
}
```

Also, please check to see whether you did, in fact, declare `testScore` anywhere. (If you did, you likely have another compile error in the program).

Comment: Should the 'testScore' Variable be after the gradePct to define to add as the condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `testScore` as a parameter of the method. And every time the method received a grade, you will get the gradepct in test method.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct grade");

        test(69);
        test(71);
        test(55);

    }

    public void test(int testScore) {

        string gradepct = "";

        if (testScore <= 60) { gradepct = "F"; }
        else if (testScore < 69) { gradepct = "D"; }
        else if (testScore < 79) { gradepct = "C"; }
        else if (testScore < 89)
        {
            gradepct = "B";
        }
        else { gradepct = "A"; }

        Console.WriteLine("You have recived the grade of gradepct:" + gradepct );
    }
}
```